# Why is AC earth connected to DC ground in laptop adapters?

Tags: power-supply, ac, dc, ground

If I were to plug this type of adapter into an ungrounded socket then voltage will leak to the DC ground through the AC filter capacitors.

So why is the DC side not left floating? What are the benefits?

Comment: In a practical off-line switching converter, the capacitor between primary and secondary ground is there to reduce EMI.  It provides a path to earth ground for high frequency noise.  [This app note](https://ac-dc.power.com/sites/default/files/product-docs/an15.pdf) might provide a more thorough explanation.

Comment: It's cheaper to earth the output than to provide sufficient isolation and filtering without grounding the output..

Some laptop power adapters have the output ungrounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nick and Jasen have it correct - All the RF energy from the laptop is internally shielded and needs to be returned to ground.